# Can we launch app with finance feature inside music app?

Tags: android

Can we launch app with finance feature inside music app? The problem is we don't know whether our app is acceptable in Google Play Store. Is there regulation which prohibits us from launching app with multiple categories: Finance, Entertainment and Social?

We used to have a finance app. We wanted to transfer all the features inside our new music app. Is it applicable and allowed by Google Play or prohibited?

Comment: This shouldn't be tagged as `ios` imho - it has nothing to do with iOS development, and pertains more to Google's developer policies.

Comment: Just read the rules from the Play Store

Comment: @Zun can you provide links to that rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the Developer Guidelines here:

[Guidelines](https://play.google.com/intl/en/about/developer-content-policy/)

It is stated that you can reorganize the tag of your App in the DEV Console. And that you shall use the most fitting tag for your app. Otherwise Google is listing your music app under finance or vice versa.